# NGXS Получение элемента, которого еще нет в хранилище

Tags: angular, redux

Изучаю NGXS и нахожу что документации очень мало а описания лучших практик еще меньше.

Например у меня есть база данных клиентов, информация о которых подгружается в хранилище через какие то абстрактные методы. И мне нужно получить информацию о конкретном клиенте. Если он уже в хранилище, то все понятно я просто забираю его. Но что если его туда еще не подгрузили или наоборот выгрузили. Как правильно обеспечить получение клиента?

Какие я вижу варианты. Сделать это в резолвере и тогда компонент гарантированно получит данные на этапе инициализации. Сделать это в компоненте напрямую но мне кажется что так нагружать компонент неправильно. Сделать это через сервис, который обеспечит проверку существования и в случае их отсутствия передаст через подписку данные в компонент. И наконец сделать это в самом сторе, что кажется мне ужасным, ведь тогда мне придется еще и валидацию и обработку ошибок также туда завести, что мне кажется нарушит кучу концепций правильной архитектуры. А также наверняка есть другие способы.

Но и сам метод проверки мне тоже не очень очевиден. Я думаю что сначала надо сделать снапшот стора, найти в нем отсутствие нужных данных и потом диспатчить их. Есть ли вариант элегантнее?

Посоветуйте как все же поступить правильно и может есть, что почитать посмотреть на эту тему.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Дисклеймер - я один из разработчиков NGXS, так что постараюсь дать ответ более развернутым :)

> Например у меня есть база данных клиентов, информация о которых подгружается в хранилище через какие то абстрактные методы. И мне нужно получить информацию о конкретном клиенте.

Я вижу 2 состояния - `clients`, `client`.

> Но что если его туда еще не подгрузили или наоборот выгрузили. Как правильно обеспечить получение клиента?

Немного непонятно, у тебя есть список клиентов, что может делать пользователь - выбирать их и видеть информацию? Нужно указать в вопросе, потому что мне например неясно.

> Сделать это в резолвере и тогда компонент гарантированно получит данные на этапе инициализации

Да, создать событие:

```
export class GetClients {
  public static readonly type = '[Clients] Get clients';
}
```

И диспатчить его в разрешителе:

```
export class GetClientsResolver implements Resolve<unknown> {
  constructor(private readonly store: Store) {}

  public resolve(): Observable<unknown> {
    return this.store.dispatch(new GetClients());
  }
}
```

> Сделать это в компоненте напрямую но мне кажется что так нагружать компонент неправильно.

Не нужно, компонент должен изначально получить готовый чанк данных через селектор:

```
export class ClientsComponent {
  @Select(ClientsState.getClients)
  public clients$: Observable<Client[]>;
}
```

> И наконец сделать это в самом сторе, что кажется мне ужасным, ведь тогда мне придется еще и валидацию и обработку ошибок также туда завести, что мне кажется нарушит кучу концепций правильной архитектуры.

Это твое субъективное мнение, но это не так. Состояние должно изолировать определенную бизнес логику, чтобы никто не бегал по файлам и не искал, что, где и как происходит.

> нарушит кучу концепций правильной архитектуры

Какие концепции нарушит? :)

> Я думаю что сначала надо сделать снапшот стора, найти в нем отсутствие нужных данных и потом диспатчить их

А зачем делать проверку если в любом случае каждый раз, когда пользователь перезагружает страницу - он должен увидеть список клиентов, верно?

P.S. - пиши в комментариях вопросы более детальней, я апдейтну ответ.

**UPD**

> если в сторе запускать проверки то будут нарушены некоторые принципы SOLID

Если расшифровать акроним SOLID и пройтись по всем принципам, то никакой принцип не нарушается :)

Тебе не нужно делать никакой проверки. Смотри, у тебя есть корневой разрешитель, который Angular запустит 1 раз для получения всех клиентов:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    resolve: [GetClientsResolver],
    children: [
      {
        path: '',
        loadChildren: () => import('path-to-clients-module')
      }
    ]
  }
];

export const AppRoutingModule = RouterModule.forRoot(routes);
```

Когда у тебя архитектура не "Redux-like", то обработку ошибок нужно производить в сервисах. Это не распространяется на компоненты, потому что иногда нужно производить обработку там (в случаях если нужно показывать ошибки пользователю, например валидация формы).

Когда у тебя появляются состояния, то обработку нужно производить в соответствующих классах, в NgRx - это классы с эффектами, в NGXS это просто класс с состоянием.

Иначе возникает циклическая зависимость:

```
ClientsService -> Actions (GetClientsFailure) -> ClientsState -> ClientsService
```

С обработкой ошибок я в принципе не вижу проблемы, например мы хотим загрузить список клиентов, но у нас упал контейнер (гипотетически) и Nginx вернул 504:

```
@State<Client[]>({
  name: 'clients',
  defaults: []
})
export class ClientsState {
  constructor(private readonly clientsService: ClientsService) {}

  @Action(GetClients)
  public getClients({ setState }: StateContext<Client[]>) {
    return this.clientsService.getClients().pipe(
      tap(clients => setState(clients)),
      catchError(() => {
        setState([]);
        return of(null);
      })
    );
  }
}
```

Где `clientsService.getClients` это:

```
return this.http.get('/api/clients');
```

Возможно я неправильно понял твой вопрос по поводу - как загрузить клиента с проверкой и тд, если у тебя есть уже их список - то нужно ли грузить клиента по ID, не проще ли просто взять его из массива?

Возможно если в списке клиентов о них неполная информация, а только что-то минимальное, например `id, name`, то можно создать дополнительное состояние, например `clientsInfo`, который будет брать нужного клиента по `id` либо загружать его:

```
type ClientsInfoStateModel = { [key: string]: Client };

export class GetClientById {
  public static readonly type = '[Clients info] Get client by ID';
  constructor(public id: string) {}
}

@State<ClientsInfoStateModel>({
  name: 'clientsInfo',
  defaults: {}
})
export class ClientsInfoState {
  public static getClientById(id: string) {
    return createSelector(
      [ClientsInfoState],
      (state: ClientsInfoStateModel) => state[id]
    );
  }

  constructor(private readonly clientsService: ClientsService) {}

  @Action(GetClientById)
  public getClientById(
    { getState, patchState }: StateContext<ClientsInfoStateModel>,
    { id }: GetClientById
  ) {
    return this.clientsService.getClientById(id).pipe(
      tap(client => {
        patchState({
          [id]: client
        });
      })
    );
  }
}
```

`public static getClientById` - это селектор, который будет возвращать из кеша полную информацию о клиенте по его `id`, либо `undefined` (если его нету).

Тогда в резолвере нужно делать проверку:

```
export class GetClientByIdResolver implements Resolve<Client> {
  constructor(private readonly store: Store) {}

  public resolve(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot): Client | Observable<Client> {
    const id = route.paramMap.get('id');
    const client = this.store.selectSnapshot(ClientsInfoState.getClientById(id));

    if (client) {
      return client;
    }

    return this.store.dispatch(new GetClientById(id)).pipe(
      map(() => this.store.selectSnapshot(ClientsInfoState.getClientById(id)))
    );
  }
}
```

В самом компоненте мы уже получим всю информацию о клиенте:

```
export class ClientInfoComponent {
  public client = this.route.data.snapshot.client;

  constructor(private readonly route: ActivatedRoute) {}
}
```

Comment: Вот это мне повезло :) Тогда примите сначала огромную благодарность за такой прекрасный продукт. Мне казалось что если в сторе запускать проверки то будут нарушены некоторые принципы SOLID. Но обдумав ваши слова я пришел к такой конструкции. В резолвере я  диспатчу `GetSpecificClient(clientId)`, потом в сторе я получаю state через `getState` делаю проверку на существование `id` если есть то возвращаю данные, если нет то делаю http запрос на сервер. Будет ли правильным сделать этот запрос через специальный сервис в котором к тому же я бы организовал обработку ошибки и валидацию ответа?

Comment: Да, я неверно или не до конца описал свою модель. У меня клиентов несколько десятков тысяч. Они подгружаются в стор по 100 штук по некоторым абстрактным необходимостям. То есть я не всегда могу взять его из массива, потому что нужного `id` там еще может не быть. Но в принципе я понял, и так и предполагал. Проверить в резолвере в снапшоте существование клиента, и если его нет то задиспатчить. Огромное спасибо за помощь.